# Need to change code to periodically execute (autosave)

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is working code. If click button, code executes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#register").click(function(){

if ($("#is_row_changed1").val() > 0) {

$.post(
"_autosave.php",
$("#form1").serialize(),
function(data) {
$('#load').html(data);
document.getElementById('is_row_changed1').value = 0;
}//function(data) {
);//$.post(

//var str = $("#form1").serialize();//this will display in #stage2 all input values like date_day1=22&date_month1=04
//$("#stage2").text(str);

}//if ($("#is_row_changed1").val() > 0) {


});//$("#register").click(function(event){
});//$(document).ready(function() {
```

I need it execute periodically, for example each 5 seconds

If `$(document).ready(function() {` change to `function autosave() {
var t = setTimeout("autosave()", 5000);` nothing happens.

What would be correct code?

**Update**
Seems got working code. Please, any comments (may be something incorrect/not good)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function() {
setTimeout(autoSavePost, 5000); 
});


function autoSavePost() {
//$("#register").click(function(){

if ($("#is_row_changed1").val() > 0) {

$.post(
"_autosave.php",
$("#form1").serialize(),
function(data) {
$('#load').html(data);
document.getElementById('is_row_changed1').value = 0;
}//function(data) {
);//$.post(

//var str = $("#form1").serialize();//this will display in #stage2 all input values like date_day1=22&date_month1=04
//$("#stage2").text(str);

}//if ($("#is_row_changed1").val() > 0) {

setTimeout(autoSavePost, 5000);

}//function autoSavePost() {
//});//$("#register").click(function(event){
});//$(document).ready(function() {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems fine, one change that i might do will be is to use setInterval

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function autoSavePost() {
        if ($("#is_row_changed1").val() > 0) {

            $.post("_autosave.php", $("#form1").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#load').html(data);
                $('#is_row_changed1').val(0)
            });
        }
    }

    setInterval(autoSavePost, 5000);
});
```